# Can I use use Visual Studio 2015 without an Internet connection?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to install VS 2015 Enterprise in a secure environment.  I can download the ISO fine, but when I try to install it I immediately get informed that I have no Internet connection.  It allows me to continue but lists 19 packages that did not get installed because I had no Internet connection.  Then when I try to use it every operation throws an error.  Even the startup screen complains of no Internet connection.

I suppose I can download and install the 19 packages separately.  Maybe that would make the errors go away.  My question is, is there something I can do configuration-wise to let VS 2015 know it should not look for resources on the Internet, and maintain normal operations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I tend to be of the "answer is never no" school, in consideration of the deafening silence here and my empty google searches there, I'm answering that there is currently no practical way of divorcing yourself from the Internet, and more specifically Microsoft resources on the Internet, while installing and using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.  A disappointing result.

I'll be happy to receive an update and be proven wrong.  Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise has a lot of promise, but it's also missing valuable utility because there is no published method of making it independent.

Comment: That seems to be the case. It requires an internet connection for some packages. e.g. Windows 10 SDK, Python Tools for VS, Java SE, Android SDK, etc etc. I wonder what is the point of having a 7GB ISO !!

Comment: Examining the MSDN article for creating an Offline Installation package (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt706497.aspx) it appears that all of the Android SDK products require an active Internet Connection for installation. The rest of the components can be configured for offline installs; but only if you do some extra work before starting the install.

Comment: Also internet will required for account activation at least once. No sure for enterprise but for community you can't continue without MS account.

Answer (score 0):

To download offline packages, you can use /layout command with VS setup(like vs_enterprise.exe) of mounted iso, see details here(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx), though I have not tried it yet. You can try "vs_enterprise.exe /noweb" command to launch and prompt setup to not connect to internet  but if there is no offline packages on ISO, in the end, installer shows list of things that were unabled to installed.
Search if those packages are available as standalone offline setup on Microsoft depeloper site.

Answer (score 0):

Our internal development network is completely isolated from any external network, i.e. no corporate network, no internet.  On a machine that is connected to the internet, download Visual studio (doesn't have to be the ISO), and on that computer run the installer with /layout switch, and choose all the items you want installed.  That will create a large folder (ours went to 22GB).  Copy this folder to your development machine.  Next, and this was the important bit for us, download the latest cumulative update for your version of the Windows O/S.  Install that, and reboot.  After this you'll be able to install Visual Studio from your large folder -- at least that worked for us (except for the Obfuscator - that wouldn't install, but I can live with that).  We have both Visual Studio Enterprise and Visual Studio Professional 2015 w/ Update 3.